# On the Young's Convolution Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that
\begin{align*}
\|f\ast g\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq\|f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})},\quad p\geq 1,
\end{align*}
where $f\ast g$ is the convolution of $f$ and $g$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f\ast g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x-y)g(y)dy,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
\end{align*}
This is the so called Young's convolution inequality.

A standard proof of such inequality uses Fubini's theorem. I wonder if there is a simple proof of the following special case that
\begin{align*}
\|\chi_{A}\ast\chi_{B}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq|A|\cdot|B|
\end{align*}
without recourse to Fubini's theorem?

Comment: It is essentially Fubini's theorem for a rectangle $A \times B$, it is not clear to me how you can avoid it.

Comment: The approach I am imagining is based on approximating $A$ and $B$ by cubes or rectangles and doing the convolution by hand in the case that $A$ and $B$ are cubes. Then you can approximate the general $A$ and $B$ by unions of cubes/rectangles.

Comment: @copper.hat Back in the day when I took the real analysis course, the professor assigned an exercise about proving the fact that $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|$ without recourse to the general Fubini's theorem, this is an exercise from Zygmund book Measure and Integral 1977, Exercise 2 in Chapter 6.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Even restricting $A,B$ to cubes or rectangles, will that really make it simpler?

Comment: Since the definition of the norm and the convolution produces a repeated integral you have to switch the order of integration one way or another. But something much weaker than Fubini theorem is enough to do it for simple functions like this. What you are proposing is essentially reproving the theorem in a special case. Instead of cubes you can also do it for continuous functions (this case was known already to Euler) and then pass to limit.

Comment: How about a linear change of variables $T(x,y) = (x-y, y)$?

Comment: @copper.hat That is clever. But then the whole matter is whether the change of variables formula is fundamental enough. I accepted the proposal, thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the issue with a change of variable is that it implies you are allowed to turn the iterated integral $\|A\ast B\|_{L^1}$ into a double integral in order to change variables with $(x,y)$ simultaneously. That means you are allowing the use of Fubini—Tonelli.

Comment: The idea of using cubes is that when you go to compute the convolution at a point $x$, $\chi_A\ast\chi_B(x) = |A\cap(x-B)|$. If $A$ and $B$ are cubes or rectangles, this intersection will always be another cube or rectangle, meaning its volume as a function of $x$ should hopefully be possible to compute based on determining the intersection. If $A$ and $B$ are just general measurable sets, I don't see any way to approach finding the measure of $A\cap(x-B)$ and doing the resulting integral in $x$.